# pyinstaller failed to execute script pyi rth pkgres

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, scheduler

I have an exe file that I made with pyinstaller and when I try to run it it gives me this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' [50728]
>
> Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

the python script contains a scheduler using BlockingScheduler from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking that works when I execute it as a python script, but return this error as an exe file.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this answer on stackoverflow (can't remember the url):
Here's what you need to do:

Step:1 `pip uninstall pyinstaller`

Step:2 `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

GoodLuck