# How to coding to change support Python OpenCV Coin Segmentation to support Box Segmentation and have File Select to select video before Segmentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, detection, image-segmentation

How to coding to change support Python OpenCV Circle (Coin) Segmentation to support Square (Box) Segmentation and have File Select to select video before Segmentation ?

I learn Coin Segmentation : Python OpenCV article with article link https://medium.com/@kongruksiamza/coin-secmentation-python-opencv-9c7a9537002c and Source Code link https://github.com/kongruksiamza/Coin-Segmentation .

I have problem to count segmentation only circle (coin) segmentation (cannot count square (box) segmentation) and no file select to select video before segmentation.

**Sample Code.**

1. `CoinDetection.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("Coin2.mp4")

while(cap.read()) :
     ref,frame = cap.read()
     roi=frame[:1080,0:1920]

     gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     gray_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(15,15),0)
     thresh=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,1)
     kernel=np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
     closing=cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,iterations=4)

     result_img=closing.copy()
     contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(result_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     counter=0
     for cnt in contours:
         area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
         if area<5000 or area > 35000:
             continue
         ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
         cv2.ellipse(roi,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
         counter+=1
    
     cv2.putText(roi,str(counter),(10,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,4,(255,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
     cv2.imshow("Show",roi)

     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

2. Sample image to have count square (box) segmentation) with link.

https://inwfile.com/s-fn/uzr1at.png

3. UI example to have File Select to select video before Segmentation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd4By.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** : I add code to have File Select to select video before Segmentation with my full source code.

I have answer credit with [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library) , [link2](https://medium.com/@taohuh/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A1%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%8C-python-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%99-exe-%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A2%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%99-1-%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%94-60ac5e5c6883) , [link3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtBTrARHJps&list=WL&index=3&t=156s) and [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445102/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres).

1. Install pyinstaller / auto-py-to-exe / win32com with command :

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
pip install auto-py-to-exe
pip install pywin32
```

2. Coding with sample.

2.1 `BoxDetection.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(filename) # Compatible with box2 mp4 video file

while(cap.read()) :
     ref,frame = cap.read()
     roi=frame[:1080,0:1920]

     gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     gray_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(25,25),0)
     thresh=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,4)
     kernel=np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
     closing=cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,iterations=4)

     result_img=closing.copy()
     contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(result_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     counter=0
     for cnt in contours:
         area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
         if area<800 :
             continue
         # ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
         # cv2.ellipse(roi,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
         counter+=1

     cv2.putText(roi,str(counter),(10,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,4,(0,0,255),4,cv2.LINE_AA)
     cv2.imshow("Show",roi)

     if cv2.waitKey(300000) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and VDO `box2.mp4` example file with link - https://doanga2007.github.io/box2.mp4

3. Open cmd and use `auto-py-to-exe` command to open `auto-py-to-exe` program , Open python file and press compile button to compile python file to exe file instantly.
4. Have `BoxDetection.exe` with link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnnnDWRrg1NbPZ3hr9mhY-t_4zry21rB/view?usp=sharing