# How to coding to fix Fatal error detected : Failed to execute script BoxDetection after use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller, detection

How to coding to fix Fatal error detected : Failed to execute script BoxDetection after use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file?

I learn to compile python code to exe file with vdo link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtBTrARHJps&list=WL&index=3&t=156s .

I have problem to after use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file and have popup error after program finished working.

```
Fatal error detected
Failed to execute script BoxDetection
```

Have popup error with picture link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNRma.jpg to ask how to coding to fix popup error to **Failed to execute script BoxDetection** problem.

**Sample Code.**

1. `BoxDetection.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(filename) # Compatible with box2 mp4 video file

while(cap.read()) :
     ref,frame = cap.read()
     roi=frame[:1080,0:1920]

     gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     gray_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(25,25),0)
     thresh=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,4)
     kernel=np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
     closing=cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,iterations=4)

     result_img=closing.copy()
     contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(result_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     counter=0
     for cnt in contours:
         area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
         if area<622 :
             continue
         # ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
         # cv2.ellipse(roi,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
         counter+=1

     cv2.putText(roi,str(counter),(10,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,4,(0,0,255),4,cv2.LINE_AA)
     cv2.imshow("Show",roi)

     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

2. `boxdetectionerrorlog.txt` with download link.

https://doanga2007.github.io/boxdetectionerrorlog.txt

3. Sample VDO `box2.mp4` with link - https://doanga2007.github.io/box2.mp4
4. `BoxDetection.exe` 64 bit use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file with download link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnnnDWRrg1NbPZ3hr9mhY-t_4zry21rB/view?usp=sharing

If open BoxDetection.exe and select sample VDO box2.mp4 , Have popup error after program finished working with picture link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYR69.jpg

5. `boxdetectionerrorlog+debug.txt` with download link.

https://doanga2007.github.io/boxdetectionerrorlog+debug.txt

6. Python Shell to describe error log after Run Module.

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
== RESTART: C:\Users\tum\Desktop\โปรแกรม BoxDetection แบบ EXE\BoxDetection.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tum\Desktop\โปรแกรม BoxDetection แบบ EXE\BoxDetection.py", line 13, in <module>
    roi=frame[:1080,0:1920]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Comment: The error is because, something does not exist? something related to `frame` maybe? i guess its the problem with video file? are you sure the path to it is correct? Try saying `print(filename)` and verify that too. Pretty sure `askopenfilename()` takes some arguements onn`

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks you to introduce , I found answer to fix Fatal error detected : Failed to execute script BoxDetection after use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file.

Comment: thne you can actually add it here and mark it as the answer

Comment: @CoolCloud I answer to fix Fatal Error tomorrow.

Comment: @CoolCloud I answer to fix Fatal Error complete at link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433819/10863080 ( Key answer to fix Fatal Error of `cv2.waitKey(300000)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good news** : I have answer to fix Fatal error detected : Failed to execute script BoxDetection after use auto-py-to-exe compile python code to exe file with my full source code.

I have answer credit with [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library) , [link2](https://medium.com/@taohuh/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A1%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%8C-python-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%99-exe-%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A2%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%99-1-%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%94-60ac5e5c6883) , [link3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtBTrARHJps&list=WL&index=3&t=156s) and [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445102/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres).

1. Install pyinstaller / auto-py-to-exe / win32com with command :

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
pip install auto-py-to-exe
pip install pywin32
```

2. Coding with sample.

2.1 `BoxDetection.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(filename) # Compatible with box2 mp4 video file

while(cap.read()) :
     ref,frame = cap.read()
     roi=frame[:1080,0:1920]

     gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     gray_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(25,25),0)
     thresh=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,4)
     kernel=np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
     closing=cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,iterations=4)

     result_img=closing.copy()
     contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(result_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     counter=0
     for cnt in contours:
         area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
         if area<800 :
             continue
         # ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
         # cv2.ellipse(roi,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
         counter+=1

     cv2.putText(roi,str(counter),(10,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,4,(0,0,255),4,cv2.LINE_AA)
     cv2.imshow("Show",roi)

     if cv2.waitKey(300000) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and VDO `box2.mp4` example file with link - https://doanga2007.github.io/box2.mp4

3. Open cmd and use `auto-py-to-exe` command to open `auto-py-to-exe` program , Open python file and press compile button to compile python file to exe file instantly.
4. Have `BoxDetection.exe` with link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnnnDWRrg1NbPZ3hr9mhY-t_4zry21rB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings with SO :D